# python re.findall vs re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Please explain me why I get different results with using re.find and re.sub

The string which I parse:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'10.10.10.10' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A78AF560CD6F8FEA4DC8205299927B6CB1B1F56A'
```

Code:

```
import re

S="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'10.10.10.10' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A78AF560CD6F8FEA4DC8205299927B6CB1B1F56A'"

U=re.compile(r'.* TO \'(.*?)\'@.*')
H=re.compile(r'.*\'@\'(.*?)\'.*')

print(U.findall(S))
print(H.findall(S))
```

So I get what I want:

```
['testuser']  
['10.10.10.10']
```

So, I want to change ip address and user, so I try to use re.sub

Code

```
import re
S="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'10.10.10.10' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A78AF560CD6F8FEA4DC8205299927B6CB1B1F56A'"

U=re.compile(r'.* TO \'(.*?)\'@.*')
H=re.compile(r'.*\'@\'(.*?)\'.*')

HOST=H.sub('another_ip',S) 
USER=U.sub('another_user',S)
print(HOST)
print(USER)
```

But I just get this:

```
another_ip
another_user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `re.sub()` you need to specifically target which part of the string are you trying to substitute. In other words, `re.sub()` would replace everything that was matched by a regular expression (well, [strictly speaking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), `the leftmost non-overlapping occurrence of a pattern`) - in your case you are replacing the complete string. Instead, you can match the user and the IP address specifically, for example:

```
>>> re.sub(r"'(\w+)'@'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'", "'another_user'@'another_ip'", S)
"GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'another_user'@'another_ip' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A78AF560CD6F8FEA4DC8205299927B6CB1B1F56A'"
```

Comment: Unescaped dots match any character but a newline.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.